# Passing object from another class to a constructor of the other in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, object, constructor

I have 2 classes - in the second one I want to pass an object of the class `CAdress` and via its `explicit constrcutor`, assign the member `ar` from the class `CStudent` the corresponding values? I would like to ask how can I do this? Thanks in advance!

```
class CAdress {
    string street;
    string postal;
    string city;
public:
    CAdress() {
        street = "Studentska #1";
        postal = "9010";
        city = "Varna";
    };
    CAdress(string st, string pos, string ct) {
        street = st;
        postal = pos;
        city = ct;
    }
};



  class CStudent : public CPerson2 {
        string fn;
        CAdress adr;
    public:
        CStudent() {
            fn = "12131547";
        }
        CStudent(string nm, CAdress add, string egnn) {
            name = nm;
            //how to give values to the adress?
            //add = ?
            egn = egnn;

        }

    };
```

Comment: what have you tried‌?

Comment: One of the most under-taught (with respect to how important it is) bits of C++ is the [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Comment: Read about initialization with initializer list https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Answer (score 1):

It is more efficient to do it like this

```
CStudent (const string& nm, const CAdress& add, const string& egnn) :
     name (nm),
     adr (add),
     egn (egnn) {}
```

For reference read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy constructor and copy the value directly. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-constructor-in-cpp/. By default the compiler provides one, but it only does the shallow copy. So its better to create one sometimes.

```
    CStudent(string nm, CAdress add, string egnn) {
        name = nm;
        adr = add;
        egn = egnn;
    }
```

Comment: "adr = new CAdress(add.street, add.postal, add.city);"
This would be valid in Java, but not in C++

Comment: OP's `CAdress` does not need user defined one.